# binomial theorem formula with all coefficients being 1

Tags: sequences-and-series

I happened to wonder that for the binomial expansion formula, if all the coefficients for each term is just 1 as opposed factorials, can we still write a nice formula without the sum sign? I really want to show some work, but I haven't got any progress yet.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like $$1+x+x^2+\dots+x^n = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} ?$$

**Edit:**

Perhaps this is what you really want:

$$a^n+a^{n-1}b+a^{n-2}b^2+\dots+b^n = \frac{a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}}{a-b} ?$$

Answer (score 0):

Old John, sorry that I don't really know how to type using math language, but I meant 
a^n + (a^n-1)(b^1) + (a^n-2)(b^2) + … + (a^2)(b^n-2) + (a^1)(b^n-1) + b^n  ,call it (*)

The original binomial expansion formula is

(a+b)^n

and it contains factorials: n choose 0, n choose 1, …, n choose n-1, n choose n as coefficients for each identical term in the formula above.

I am trying to see if there is a nice formula like (a+b)^n to express (*).

Thanks!

Comment: To format math with $\LaTeX$, just  insert '$' signs around what you want formatted. Also, your clarification would have been much better as a comment on his answer, not an answer on its own. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot John. That was what I was trying to get. It seems that I have no enough reputation to vote up for you. But many thanks! Also, I will learn to edit and comment, John WO. Thank you.